# Scala anonymous functions

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming, closures, anonymous-function

Why does my anonymous function not work? 
Compiler shows me an error on line with

```
foreach((line: String) => {
```

My code:

```
Source.fromFile(siteDir.getPath).getLines()
    .map(_.trim())
    .filter(!_.isEmpty())
    .foreach((line: String) => { // I got here "error: type mismatch; found   : Unit required: String"
        val pos = line.indexOf('=')
        if (pos != -1) {
            val key = line.substring(0, pos).trim()
            val value = line.substring(pos + 1).trim()
            readMeCache(siteId.get) + (key -> value)
        }
    })
```

What is the right way to fix it?

Comment: I think your code sample is missing something.  Is this whole block of code supposed to return something (and be assigned to a var/val or be returned as the result of a method)?  If so, can you expand your code sample a bit more and also provide some more explanation to what this code is trying to do. If you want this block to return something, then `foreach` is the wrong function to use.

Comment: @cmbaxter, yes, you are right. Fixed

Comment: @tmporaries you should delete the question then

Comment: 2 remarks: your later trim statements seem obsolete + maybe you can use split instead of index of and substring.